# user id in Azure mobile app service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

In Azure Mobile App server, with client initiated authentication on device, we get userid (aka sid), now when I want to create a user record using mobile app service the sid is not available for the first time. Only information I have at the backend is, by reading claims with "NameIdentifier".

string uniqueId = creds.UserClaims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))?.Value;

SO I am curious whether is this the right way to get user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the right way to get the user claims.  For more information, check out Chapter 2 of my book:  https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/authorization/

Comment: Thanks Adrian, Just wanted to double confirm, this uniqueID will not change in future, because I am going to use this as my primary key to store the user 's information

Comment: You want to store the stable_sid, which is part of the payload from /.auth/me - this is guaranteed not to change given the same auth settings.  If you change the auth settings, it may change though.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I started using stable_sid. I also find this information

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Understanding-User-Ids